# Invite external user to Azure B2C using email address as their username

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I want to be able to create a new user in our Azure B2C instance using their preferred email address as the username they will use when accessing our web portal.

I'm using the Invitation Microsoft Graph API to invite new users This sends them an email and they then signup with us. This however assigns them a unique username using a combination of their email and our domain i.e. myemail_adomain.com#EXT#@our_verified_domain.com.

This leads to a terrible UX as users need to remember this very unmemorable username. Remembering passwords is enough of a challenge for users as it is.

If I create a user inside the Azure B2C portal I can give them any email address I want and not one of our verified domains using **Create Azure AD B2C user**

[image]

I want to be able to use this method but via an API.

The first 2 options, Create and Invite user, are available via the Microsoft Graph [Inviations API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
and the [Create User API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) but I can't find a way to do option 3.

The Create API won't allow unverified domains and the Invite API creates the unique username which is very user unfriendly.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

The other option is to get them to signup themselves via a signup user flow but I'd rather avoid this as I want control over who is allowed to sign up.

Answer (score 1):

This sample JSON will create the kind of user that you want (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

```
{
  accountEnabled: true,
  displayName: '<displayName>',
  givenName: '<givenName>',
  surname: '<surname>',
  identities: [
    {
      signInType: 'emailAddress',
      issuer: <issuer>,
      issuerAssignedId: '<email>'
    }
  ],
  passwordProfile : {
    password: '<password>',
    forceChangePasswordNextSignIn: false
  },
  passwordPolicies: "DisablePasswordExpiration",
}
```

`<issuer>` would be your `onmicrosoft.com` config value (from the B2C portal).

Note that this does not do the invite that you have asked for, but it will let you create emails such as `someuser@gmail.com`

Answer (score -1):

•   You can surely ***create a user in Azure AD B2C tenant through Microsoft Graph API*** by following the below documentation link for that purpose: -

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http**

Ensure that **you have ‘User.ReadWrite.All’ and ‘Directory.ReadWrite.All’ permissions for ‘Application’ and ‘Delegated’ permissions type** and the same **permissions are consented for Microsoft Graph API in the explorer** also with **‘Admin Consent’**. Once, these are done, then execute the below command in Graph API as shown below: -

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
Content-type: application/json

{
 "accountEnabled": true,
 "displayName": "Adele Vance",
 "mailNickname": "AdeleV",
 "userPrincipalName": "AdeleV@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
 "passwordProfile" : {
 "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
 "password": "xWwvJ]6NMw+bWH-d"
 }
 }
```

[image: User creation through graph API]

`As you can see, I don’t have sufficient privileges, so I can’t create a user in Azure AD B2C tenant`.

The output will be as below after successful execution of the above Graph API command: -

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Content-type: application/json

{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
"id": "87d349ed-44d7-43e1-9a83-5f2406dee5bd",
"businessPhones": [],
"displayName": "Adele Vance",
"givenName": "Adele",
"jobTitle": "Product Marketing Manager",
"mail": "AdeleV@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
"mobilePhone": "+1 425 555 0109",
"officeLocation": "18/2111",
"preferredLanguage": "en-US",
"surname": "Vance",
"userPrincipalName": "AdeleV@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
}
```

Comment: Yes I can do this but only for verified domains. This won't work for example for @gmail.com email addresses.